# Learning ArcObjects with VBA and .NET?

Tags: arcobjects, .net, references, vba

I am using arcgis from last 3 years. but it was only limited by button pressing.

I want to learn ArcObjects VBA and .NET.

Can you suggest me some reference books?

Answer (score 1):

I find that *Beginning ArcGIS for Desktop Development Using .Net* ([Publisher](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-ArcGIS-for-Desktop-Development-using-NET.productCd-1118442539.html)) to be useful.  They break down the operations into decent little exercises that are fairly practical.  Plus, you can download their code from the website.

**Other Suggestions**
If you are better with Java, you can also do ArcObjects in that language, too.  I don't believe there is much support for VBA anymore.  I think that was mostly MapObjects.

You might find that learning python and ArcPy to be a good starting point to get the flow of ESRI processes.